# How to implement a Photoshop like effect OilPaint effect in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, filter, paint, photoshop

So the closest of what I found is [this Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39049) implementation. Yet Mathematica is not opensource nor easily includable in other applications... So I wonder how to do  Photoshop like effect OilPaint effect in OpenCV?

Example input data:
[image]

Example Result:
[image]

Example Difference (note one can not really detect in difference-image any patterns not included in processing result):
[image]

And the best thing is it processed image looks close to what experts see in original image:
[image]

Images [source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248516768_Structural_evolution_of_the_Orange_Basin_gravity-driven_system_offshore_Namibia).

So how to implement a Photoshop like effect OilPaint effect in OpenCV (in Python or C++)?

Comment: You might find some useful functions in the computational photography module.

Comment: [Have you seen this](https://hackernoon.com/https-medium-com-matteoronchetti-pointillism-with-python-and-opencv-f4274e6bbb7b)?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a classic form of the oil painting effect in Python/OpenCV. Simply apply some morphology open to the image and then brighten the darker regions a little using cv2.normalize.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("windmill.jpg")

# apply morphology open to smooth the outline
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (6,6))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# brighten dark regions
result = cv2.normalize(morph,None,20,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("windmill_oilpaint.jpg", result)

cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("OPEN", morph)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks more like dot-blobs than directed Photoshop-like effect Oil Paint strokes...

Comment: @DuckQueen I'm also curious how it was done in Adobe. I implemented something similar in my Play Store app (Tactile Paint) where I use texture, vector filed, LIC and then finally blend with the original image. However, you can use white noise instead of texture.